# For loop in R can't retrieve the number of rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to use a for loop in R to get the number of rows in dataframes.

```
year1<-c("2001","2002","2003")
countries1<-c("Canada","USA","Mexico")
color1<-c("black","red","blue")

year2<-c("2010","2011","2012")
countries2<-c("France","Germany","Japan")
color2<-c("white","yellow","green")

df1<-data.frame(year1,countries1,color1)
df2<-data.frame(year2,countries2,color2)

for (i in c(df1,df2))
{
nb<-nrow(i)
print(nb)
}
```

I expect to get 3 and 3 (as each dataframe has 3 rows) but I get 6 "NULL" instead. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can place it in a `list`, loop through the `list` and `print` the number of rows

```
for(dat in list(df1, df2)) {nb <- nrow(dat); print(nb)}
#[1] 3
#[1] 3
```

---

The issue with concatenation (`c`) is - it `unclass`es the `data.frame` and convert it to a `list` of `vector`.  As there are 3 columns each in the data.frame, it would be a `list` of `length` 6 (i.e. 6 vector`s)

```
str(c(df1, df2))
#List of 6
# $ year1     : Factor w/ 3 levels "2001","2002",..: 1 2 3
# $ countries1: Factor w/ 3 levels "Canada","Mexico",..: 1 3 2
# $ color1    : Factor w/ 3 levels "black","blue",..: 1 3 2
# $ year2     : Factor w/ 3 levels "2010","2011",..: 1 2 3
# $ countries2: Factor w/ 3 levels "France","Germany",..: 1 2 3
# $ color2    : Factor w/ 3 levels "green","white",..: 2 3 1
```